# Find u that minimizes the integral mean

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, control-theory

How do I find $u : [0,\infty) \to  \mathbb{R}^m$ that minimizes
\begin{equation}
J(u(\cdot)) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t L(x(\tau),u(\tau)) d \tau,
\end{equation}
subject to
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t))
\end{equation}
?

My fist impression is that I cannot use optimal control theory/calculus of variations since the performance measure is *not*
\begin{equation}
J(u(\cdot)) = \int_0^{\infty} L(x(\tau),u(\tau)) d \tau.
\end{equation}

Thanks

Comment: If $\lim_{\tau\to\infty}L(x(\tau),u(\tau))$ happens to exist, then $J(u)$ is equal to that limit. I would begin by optimizing among the controls for which the limit exists, and then consider whether having persistent oscillation in $L(x(\tau),u(\tau))$ can help to minimize $J$  further.